# MAC адреса все правила валидации

Tags: валидация, mac, адрес

Какие есть правила валидации для МАК адресов, кроме того, что они вида НН:НН:НН:НН:НН:НН и содержат [0-9A-Fa-f]?
Исправлено: уточнила - FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF - специализированный, нам такой не подходит. Есть ли еще подобные адреса?

Comment: Почему f'ки невалидны? И там более, просто на ff?

Comment: мне начальник сказал, что этот адрес невалидный точно, это я решила, что потому что начинается с ff. Мое задание - определить все правила невалидности

Comment: Мне неизвестны причины, по которым какие-то mac-адреса являются невалидными. Точно с ip не перепутали?

Comment: Ну конкретно `FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF` зарезервирован для броадкаста, так что не может быть ни у какого устройства

Comment: уточнила - FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF - специализированный, нам такой не подходит. Есть ли еще подобные?

Comment: Ну, наверное странно использовать мультикаст-адреса. Всё остальное вполне себе валидно. https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC-%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81#%D0%A1%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0_MAC-%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%B0

Comment: можете подсказать, как можно узнать, что нулевой бит единица?

Answer (score 0):

В общем, помогла [эта статья](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC-%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81#%D0%A1%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0_MAC-%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%B0).

В 1-м актете переводим нулевой бит в двоичную систему исчисления

- если 0, значит unicast и он нам подходит
- если 1 - multicast и он нам не подходит